# Grid with "decoupled" scrolling (aka "frozen" rows and columns)

Tags: .net, wpf

Here is, roughly, what I'm trying to achieve:

[illustration http://namefa.mine.nu/alignmentproblem.png](http://namefa.mine.nu/alignmentproblem.png)

The green part is fixed.
Cells in the orange (or pink?) part are editable.
Cells in the blue part are also editable.
The `[add fridge]` button adds another column.

Now the tricky part:
The blue+green parts should, together, be scrollable vertically.
The blue+orange parts should, together, be scrollable horizontally.
(the dark red thingies represent scrollbars)

One can see the logic behind this: I must be able to edit product quantities for any (reasonable) number of fridges and products, even if they don't all fit on the screen. But I must never scroll either fridge names or product names out of sight.

I would like to accomplish this layout solely in XAML, with bindings (an `ObservableCollection<Fridge>` immediately jumps to mind). Writing custom converters also would be acceptable. The main point is to avoid creating/managing UI elements programmatically.

A few considerations from my previous thoughts and experiments:

1. Can't use `Grid`, since it can't autogenerate columns from sequence
2. A series of nested `ItemsControl`s could work, but then I run into the problem of aligning items from different sequences (i.e. blue cells with either orange or green ones - depending on the direction of nesting) - see my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385419/align-controls-sizes).
3. Bonus points for resizing the fridge columns. So far I've only managed to find `GridSplitter`, but it only works with grid.

Comment: The common terminology for columns and rows that do not move when scrolling is "frozen". Searching for "frozen columns" will get you more suitable results.

Comment: Looked there. So far I can only see third-party components, mostly expensive ones. Besides, people usually ask for frozen *columns*, while I need to freeze both columns and rows, and the frozen row cannot be "header" - it has to contain custom controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question just so I can accept it: this is called "frozen columns" and "frozen rows" and no, there is noting out of the box for the rows case.